# CassandraRepository - no viable alternative at input '2021-01'

Tags: java, cassandra

I want to do this operation in my java CassandraRepository with using @Query annotation:

```
select * from TABLE_A where month IN
('2021-01',
 '2021-02',
 '2021-03',
 '2021-04',
 '2021-05',
 '2021-06',
 '2021-07',
 '2021-08',
 '2021-09',
 '2021-10',
 '2021-11',
 '2021-12')
AND user_id = '1';
```

In my CassandraRepository:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE user_id = ?0 AND month IN ?1")
List<UserListenCountByMonth> findByUserIdAndYear(String userId, List<String> year);
```

But it gets error:

> Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:84
> **no viable alternative at input** '2021-01' (...WHERE user_id = '1' AND [month] IN...)

I checked on debug and there is no problem with my String List. What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old versions of CassandraRepository need parentheses in your @Query.

So, change:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE user_id = ?0 AND month IN ?1")
```

to:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE user_id = ?0 AND month IN (?1)")
```